# Several examples about template partial ordering to which GCC and Clang disagree

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

The first example is

```cpp
template <class... T> struct V {}; 
template <class... Ts, class... Us> void Foo(V<Ts...>, V<Us&...>) {} // #3 
template <class... Us> void Foo(V<>, V<Us&...>) {}                   // #4 
void h() { 
   Foo(V<>(), V<>()); 
}
```

The above example is mentioned in [CWG2235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2235). In that paper, which says `#4` is a better candidate. However, GCC and Clang have [disagreements](https://godbolt.org/z/sb3bxMPce) with this example. I think GCC is correct, my reason is, Take `#4` as argument template and `#3` as parameter template, the deductions are successful for each pair that is used to determine the ordering.
Instead, when take `#3` as argument template and `#4` as parameter template, the following rules is applied here
[temp.deduct.type#9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.type#9)

> During partial ordering, if A<sub>i</sub> was originally a pack expansion:
>
> > - if P does not contain a template argument corresponding to A<sub>i</sub> then A<sub>i</sub> is ignored;
> > - otherwise, if P<sub>i</sub> is not a pack expansion, template argument deduction fails.

That means the deduction is still successful for each pair. Finally, there's no special rule in section [temp.deduct.partial] to determine which is more specialized. Hence, it should be ambiguous here which should be GCC's opinion.

For this example, if I have some misunderstanding, please point it out.

---

Now, consider a bit complex example that GCC and Clang also disagree.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A { };
template<class T> 
struct B {
    template<class R> 
    int operator*(R) {
        std::cout<<"#1\n";
        return 0;  
    }
};

template<class R> 
int operator*(B<A>&&, R){
  std::cout<<"#2\n";
  return 0;
}
int main(){
    B<A>{} * 0;
}
```

GCC considers the example as ambiguous while Clang chooses `#1`. This time, I'm still a proponent of GCC. My reason is
[temp.func.order#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.func.order#3)

> For a function template M with cv-qualifiers cv that is a member of a class A:
>
> > - The type X(M) is “rvalue reference to cv A” if the optional ref-qualifier of M is && or if M has no ref-qualifier and the positionally-corresponding parameter of the other transformed template has rvalue reference type; if this determination depends recursively upon whether X(M) is an rvalue reference type, it is not considered to have rvalue reference type.

It means that the implicit parameter of `#1` should be `B<A>&&` during the ordering partial. Which is identical with the first parameter in `#2` and the other pair can also be deduced successfully in both directions. Hence, `#1` and `#2` should be ambiguous here too.

In general, in these two examples, I agree with the result processed by GCC. If I misunderstand something, please point it out.

Comment: I tought partial specialization of function templates wasn't even allowed?

Comment: @JHBonarius - It isn't. Those are overloads.

Comment: @JHRonarius It allows here since usual rank didn't determine which is better; So, partial ordering occurs here.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica whoops, yeah. I probably had my glasses on upside down 